# Why is this bad topology happening

Tags: vertices, topology

i was trying to create my first room art , i started with a cube , deleting its one vertex , then i extruded three faces , finally , i started to model a sofa , but then i figured this bad topology at the corner of the sofas hand-rest

[image]
i tried to fix by changing the technique of miking it , earlier i  made by extruding the face , but then i also tried extruding edges , but the problem doesn't seem to vanish , here is a better shot in edit mode
[image]

the problem doesnt exist in edit mode
here is the file
[image]

Comment: hello, hard to tell where is the problem, please share your file

Comment: okay wait please

Comment: added the blender file

Comment: there are a lot of faces overlapping, you didn't model it the right way, maybe re-do it from scratch, maybe follow some basic tutorials about modeling, like the ones by Grant Abbitt

Comment: but how is it possible , i just took a face and extruded it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of faces overlapping, or vertices that seem to be part of a face but actually are not, etc, you didn't model it the right way. Also, as pointed out by Lemon, you use a *Mirror* modifier but your mesh go beyond the center of the mirroring. Maybe re-do it from scratch, and maybe follow some basic tutorials about modeling.

If I just take one example: If I select this vertex...

[image]

... and then move it...

[image]

... we can see that it was not part of the face.

Comment: main problem is due to the mirror modifier as parts of the mesh are in both sides of the mirror.

Comment: @Nxdhin2005, the object origin is not at the center.

Comment: ok I didn't notice there was a mirror modifier, I only shared the first problem I found, I'll edit  ;)

Comment: But when i removed the cavity , it got fixed

Comment: Yes I was not sure about the problem you were talking about but I thought it might have to do with your bad topology

Answer (score -3):

I solved it , it was happening because of the CAVITY ENABLED.

Comment: No it's not happening because of the cavity. It's a problem of the topology. Cavity can exaggerate the bad topology but wont ruin the mesh